# Can Mypy overload single objects and unpacked tuples?

Tags: python, mypy

The following is easy enough to implement at runtime, but it seems impossible to express in Mypy.

Using the `*` unpacking (for its nice compactness, e.g. `foo(1, 2, ...)`) I also want to express the case when there's a single element, because requiring to unpack the single tuple adds a lot of unnecessary indexing. However, it doesn't seem to be possible to disambiguate in any way:

```py
from typing import overload


@overload
def foo(a: int) -> int: # Impossible to distinguish inputs from overload below
    ...


@overload
def foo(*a: int) -> tuple[int, ...]:
    ...


def foo(*a: int | tuple[int, ...]) -> int | tuple[int, ...]:
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    return a


assert foo(1) == 1 # This is the expected, but how would the type checker know?
assert foo(1, 2) == (1, 2) # This is obviously the correct signature
```

Is avoiding the unpacking altogether really the only way?

Comment: Anytime you have an issue like this, ask yourself what is gained (aside from letting the caller be lazy) by defining an API like this instead of one like `foo(a: tuple[int,...])` and simply requiring the caller to use `foo((1,))` instead of `foo(1)`?

Comment: `overload` has its uses, but I don't consider letting you abbreviate an iterable of length 1 as a scalar to be a good one.

Comment: The problem is that returning a tuple is fine in an assignment, but not an expression like `pandas.pipe(foo)` which expects a single in/out. It seems quite redundant to have to write `df.pipe(foo(df)[0])` or create a task-specific function instead of overloading the signature. And sometimes I've found myself requiring transforming many dataframes for compatibility purposes, where the `*` style becomes very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*args` means *0 or more* positional arguments, so you need better `@overload` signatures:

- If only one argument is passed, return that.
- If there are *at least* 2 arguments passed (2 concrete + 0 or more), return a tuple of such arguments.

Those can be translated to type hints as follow:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=bb8d52e8be8a2e4ab6dce9a561776b88), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMpgBuApiADZgCGAJgDRQAqixAapSPUwq%2BwwK4IyxALAAoMQygBeRszYgAFAHIGSgJQSATNKizu85Q03qJAZx1ceIfoOKHTJ8aIACRUhRpjqxYFGBgwBUoALkZ6AHo1KABaAD5GYLFdXQA6NLExVxJyKmovHz8AoIAGUIZ6SgBGMs0I%2BgAqEGJTGFD6hlMouNgBIQBtcsZaqHbTAF1E0WSoNJSM0W9ff0CQsKhwhqaWto6u%2BMkAHx7bAYaOiaTkpF8hFAUtmCipGVLL6d0mmD4QFChKN6gAM%2B31%2BQU2zUe8zETRIlDIAH14NwFMsFJU1FF3u8AMRQCCIOBQABkUAQcBASDQAAt8FJ4qgYNDiLCEUi7KjKvRNBisbpcfiycTSeTKTTpPEvicGfQGWMmSzEcwUUVOVBNCl6EoAMzqTH8gm86Z0479aV%2BDwwegAGSQMFIcL62qUYzlU0N7o9fOFFOp%2BF5xslppQlvNVBDLRArrEqMxnrjuNI4BA0aKwwARuwdAAWWPxqCJ3BiIA), [PEP 695 syntax](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMpgBuApiADZgCGAJgLABQDAAkaRTQ9ccFMGGAG0AKgF0AFJQBcUIQBooAegCUUALQA%2BGZIZRdUAHSGGzVuSp16XHn0FyZAJnkAqIQGdxlAAzS7lAIw%2BjorOIMSuMNIurioasACuCGTEwvJCQVEi2vR6BkaMlty8-ClQGRI%2B8gohYRGlbjGaQlAAPvGJyXYZWTlIPEkoYqHhKgC8I1DeOjl6oTBxIChQlFO6K1Cz84vL%2BQyhJJRkAPrwCMRiNmJ%2BSirT0wDEUBCIcFAAZFAIcCBIaAAW%2BCNNKgYLtiPsjiczhc-PJ7NdbroHk9Pm8Pl8fv8oIC2kkBMD5MCRKDwcdEFD%2BJdYfp5AByADMNPhUCRzwROWxc3aeJQMHkwHYvKgABkkDBSAcBPSaSIidk2fKFYi0d8-vgERyErj8bwBfJwiBZQwLjdFaaHqRwCAjRSggAjSggLFQAAsJrNUAtuAYQA))</sub>

```py
from typing import overload, TypeVar, TypeVarTuple

T = TypeVar('T')
T2 =  TypeVar('T2')
Ts = TypeVarTuple('Ts')

@overload
def foo(a: T, /) -> T:
    ...

@overload
def foo(a0: T, a1: T2, /, *rest: *Ts) -> tuple[T, T2, *Ts]:
    ...

def foo(a: T, /, *rest: *Ts) -> T | tuple[T, *Ts]:
    if len(rest) == 0:
        return a
    
    return (a, *rest)
```

```py
reveal_type(foo(1))           # mypy & pyright => int
reveal_type(foo(1, 2))        # mypy & pyright => tuple[int, int]
reveal_type(foo(1, 2., '3'))  # mypy           => tuple[int, float, Literal['3']]
                              # pyright        => tuple[int, float, str]

foo()                         # error
foo(2, bar = 4)               # error
```